# Uploading an application in google play store

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

I want to upload an application which has been fully developed using java but I want to know the steps involving uploading the application in google play store.

Can anyone help me out. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a developer account (or register from the one of your company). See more information here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

Comment: I have done with registration but I am nt getting the proper page.

Comment: What "proper page" are you looking for? every step should be mentioned in the link given

Comment: Okei I ll try it out with the link you have given and get back to you asap!! Tnq :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the link below. You will get all the answers you need here. Also, google things out if you face further problems.

[Google playstore app upload help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en)

Comment: Thank You for your response